# PHP Sales Tax Calculating

Tags: php

So I can't quite figure out what is wrong here. I am trying to calculate Sales Tax into a grand total. I'm trying to get two variables here:

```
A. The total amount of sales tax that is being charged (i.e. $0.61 for sales tax)
B. The Grand total including the item price times the quantity plus the sales tax.
```

My script is as below, The way I have this set up right now it only adds a penny to the sub total. (instead of $7.00 the total is $7.01)

If the sub total after each item is `$7.00` and the tax rate is `8.650%` then the tax total should be `$0.61` and the grand total should be `$7.61` but it's making it `$7.01` instead.

```
public function invoice_totals($invoice_id)
{
    $query = $this->CI->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->CI->db->from('invoice_to_items');
    $query = $this->CI->db->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id);
    $query = $this->CI->db->join('items', 'items.item_id = invoice_to_items.item_id');
    $query = $this->CI->db->get();
    $items = $query->result();

    $sub_total      = '0.00';
    $grand_total    = '0.00';
    $tax_rate       = '0.0865';
    $tax_total      = '0.00';

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $sub_total = $sub_total + ($item->item_price*$item->item_qty);

        $tax_total = $tax_total + ($sub_total * $tax_rate) / 100;
    }

    $grand_total = $grand_total + $sub_total + $tax_total;

    return array(
        'sub_total'     =>  number_format($sub_total,2),
        'tax_total'     =>  number_format($tax_total, 2),
        'grand_total'   =>  number_format($grand_total,2),
    );
}
```

The main line I am concerned with in this question is:

```
$tax_total = $tax_total + ($sub_total * $tax_rate) / 100;
```

Comment: Remove the division by 100, your $tax_rate is already in decimal form. Also, initialize your variables with numbers not strings.

Comment: Well then you should probably not be implementing something that can presumably even have legal implications if done wrong …

Comment: Good. I'm glad. Bring on the hate. Just pulls me forward more :) Thanks for the encouragement. :) hahahahaahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're applying your taxes to your subtotal on EVERY iteration of the loop.

let's say there's 3 items: $5, $15, $40

```
loop #1:

subtotal = 0 + ($5 * 1) = $5
total = 0 + ($5 + 8.65%) = $5.43

loop #2:  $5.43 + ($15 * 1) = $20.43
total = $5.43 + ($20.43 + 8.65%) = etc...

etc...
```

your #2 item has now double-taxed the first item, and your third item will be TRIPLE taxing the first item and DOUBLE taxing the second item, etc...

As well, your tax rate value is ALREADY a decimal (0.0865), yet you're doing a /100 division as if you had `$tax_rate = 8.65`. So effectively your tax rate is really 0.0865%

Your loop should be:

```
$taxrate = 8.65; // % value

foreach($items as $item) {
   $item_sub = $items->quantity * $items->price;
   $item_total = $item_sub * ($taxrate / 100);

   $grand_total = $grand_total + $item_total;
}
```

Comment: Also he should define the tax rate as float and not as string.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: php won't care in this case.

Comment: In this case PHP will convert it to float, but do that one hundred times and you'll notice it if you're testing the runtime.